# Unable to scroll constraint layout inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to add constraint layout inside ScrollView but the layout is not scrolling
What i have already tried:

-> Putting constraint layout inside nestedscrollview

-> Putting scrollview inside of another constraint layout and setting height = "0dp", constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent", constraintTop_toTopOf = "bottom"

-> Adding `android:isScrollContainer="true"`

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Large antique wardrobe"
            android:textColor="@color/black1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/transit_charge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvItemName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvItemName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/required_by"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvItemName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
            tools:text="$20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRequiredByDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="dsafsadfsfdsadfasdfsadfsadf"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
            tools:text="Fri · May 18" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvItemsImages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvItemName"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvPrice"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPrice">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvItemsImages">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/shape_ring"
                android:tint="@color/pickup"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/pickup_address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPickupAddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView19"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPickupAdditionalInfo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView22"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView22" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/additional_info"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvPickupAddress"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPickupAddress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/additional_info"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvDropOffAddress"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDropOffAddress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDropOffAddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView24"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDropOffAdditionalInfo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView27"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView27" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/drop_off_address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary50"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvPickupAdditionalInfo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPickupAdditionalInfo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/shape_ring"
                android:tint="@color/drop_off"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDropOffAddress"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <com.capcorp.utils.DottedLine
                android:id="@+id/dottedLine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="It's a large teakwood wardrobe. Handle with care. Approx. Dimensions are 2 ft. by 4 ft"
                android:textColor="@color/black1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvDropOffAdditionalInfo"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDropOffAdditionalInfo" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

-->

I'm using this constraint layout of version:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is put the second `ConstraintLayout` inside the outer `ConstraintLayout`, which don't make sense, and set its height to `0dp`. This way `ConstraintLayout` will auto arrange this `View` to match the parent size and the content is never scrollable.

Two things need to be fixed here:

- Use 1 `ConstraintLayout` only for the root container. `ConstraintLayout` itself is already "heavy" enough to arrange your layout with tons of constraint.
- don't use `layout_height="0dp"` for any `View` inside `ConstraintLayout` so the parent's height expands to wrap all the children's height

Comment: Silly mistake. The inner constraint layout you are talking about is the same layout I was using in my project in different place. So  I just copied all the layout with constraint layout as a root also. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I can help